# laravel 5 - Eloquent Relationships (permissions table)

Tags: php, laravel, relationships, eloquent

I think am struggling to get the relationships correctly in the scenario I have.

I have three tables

```
Table: users

|  id  |   username  |
----------------------
|   1  |    pluto    |
|------|-------------|

Table: permissions

|  id  |   user_id   |   level_id   |   app_id   |
--------------------------------------------------
|   1  |      1      |       2      |     9      |
|------|-------------|--------------|------------|

Table: levels

|  id  |    level    |
----------------------
|   1  |    admin    |
|------|-------------|
|   2  |   manager   |
|------|-------------|
|   3  |    editor   |
|------|-------------|
```

The result I am looking to get is

```
manager //through User:: model or Auth::
```

I would like to get a value from levels table in level column either through User model. This is the last version on what I have in my classes...

```
class User extends Authenticatable 
{
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Permissions');
    }
}


class Permissions extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }

    public function levels()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Levels');
    }
}


class Levels extends Model
{
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Modules\Ecosystem\Entities\permissions');
    }
}
```

Using this in the controller I am able to retrieve values from permissions table. However I am unable to get values from levels table...

```
$user = User::with('permissions')->find(Auth::user()->id);
```

However I am unable to get values from levels table when I try this...

```
$user = User::with('permissions.levels')->find(Auth::user()->id);
```

That produces an error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'levels.permissions_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `levels` where `levels`.`permissions_id` in (1))
```

I understand that I am not understanding exactly how relationships would work in this instance but I don't want to just guess a solution. I'd like to understand it.

The thing is ,, Levels table serves only as a list of permission levels (roles). I recognize that I can define permission levels in some other way but for the moment this is how everything is set up.

Comment: I think you are defining the Permission-Level relationship exactly the opposite of what it should be. A `Permission` `belongsTo` a `Level` and a `level` `hasMany` `Permission`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a usual user permission system, where 'roles' is replaced by 'levels', then you need to reorganized your tables and relationships.

```
Table: users

|  id  |   username  |    level_id    |
---------------------------------------
|   1  |    pluto    |       2        |
|------|-------------|----------------|


Table: levels

|  id  |    level    |
----------------------
|   1  |    admin    |
|------|-------------|
|   2  |   manager   |
|------|-------------|
|   3  |    editor   |
|------|-------------|


Table: permissions

|  id  |  level_id   |   app_id   |
-----------------------------------
|   1  |      2      |     9      |
|------|-------------|------------|
```

So now User

```
hasOne('App\Levels', 'level_id');
```

Levels

```
hasMany('Modules\Ecosystem\Entities\permissions', 'level_id');
```

Permissions

```
belongsTo('App\Levels', 'level_id');
```

That is probably what you were trying to do, and it will works.

However, if many roles may have similar permissions, e.g: admin, manager & editor can all have access to a 'Page' or 'Content' or whatever that they all have access to, then you will need a 4th table to have many-to-many relationship between permissions and levels.

```
Table: permissions

|  id  |   app_id   |
---------------------
|   1  |     9      |
|------|------------|

Table: levels_permissions

|  level_id   |   permission_id   |
-----------------------------------
|      2      |         1         |
|-------------|-------------------|
```

With this, in Levels

```
belongsToMany('Modules\Ecosystem\Entities\permissions', 'levels_permissions', 'level_id', 'permission_id');
```

Inverse the relation in Permissions

```
belongsToMany('App\Levels', 'levels_permissions', 'permission_id', 'level_id');
```

In both approaches, you can now do

```
$user = User::with('levels.permissions')->find(Auth::user()->id);
```

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. The scenario is that a user can have one level_id for one app_id and another level_id for some other app_id.

Comment: My permissions table tracks the permissions relationship between users and apps really.

Comment: "It tracks the the permissions between users and apps really" then remove the level_id in the permissions table. Then a User hasMany permissions and an app belongsTo a user. Easier for you.

Comment: "a user can have one level_id for one app_id and another level_id for some other app_id", therefore different permission configuration (level) on different apps (or none)... so I can't remove the level_id,,, both level and user have many permissions (I got this part sorted out).. However I am still left with not being able to stitch a suitable join... I need user/auth model to have access to level,,, Permissions see the level,,, User sees permissions,, the User does not see the level,,,